# Fullscreen Android app for use in ROM

Tags: android, android-source

I'm developing an Android tablet app where I need to show fullscreen content. Entering and closing the app is done using a dedicated physical button on the device. When the button is pressed I want all other traces of the Android UI to disappear, and then reappear when we press the button again. I.e., a fullscreen app that is placed on top everything else.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I've tried various approaches to no avail: 
* Adding SYSTEM_UI_FLAGS* doesn't work for this purpose, as the SystemUI will reappear when touching the screen. Ideally we would also not like the animation when opening our fullscreen app.
* Adding a separate layer on top of what we believe is all other layers, but the SystemUI is still shown

Some kind of layering must be preserved. I.e., I need to show incoming call dialogs on top of the fullscreen app.

***Please note:*** This question is about development in the framework/system part of Android. I'm not looking for answers on how to do it in regular user apps.

Comment: On the whole, Stack Overflow is focused on app questions, not OS customization questions. You may have better luck using sites that cater to ROM modders and the like (e.g., XDA's forums).

Comment: Still this is in fact a question about developing an app - just one not subject to the same restrictions that one distributed by a 3rd party would be.

Comment: @CommonsWare: That's what I suspected. But I think Stack Exchange still would serve like a good knowledge base for platform related stuff as well, and that could also fill a gap that modder communities doesn't serve.

Comment: @Chris Stratton The modifications needed to achieve what the questions was about needs to be done in the Android framework and/or SystemUI. Admittedly the app needs to adhere to these changes, but probably (hopefully) that will just be by adding a custom system UI visibility flag to the decorView.

Comment: Yes - generally speaking, if you are changing the program code of Android itself you are on topic here just as you would be when developing an app.  But if you were only changing assorted configuration files in someone else's otherwise complete build, then it nears the border of off topic.